# Precautions that needs to be taken before shutting down a sandbox?

Tags: sandbox

I have a situation where I need to shut down some of our unused sandboxes. I have gone through Salesforce's documentations regarding this. But the documents doesn't provide much insight on this. The documents just state below.

> Deleting a sandbox permanently erases the sandbox and all data in it,
>   including any outbound change sets that have been uploaded from the
>   sandbox.

I have some additional questions regarding this.

1. What does it mean deleting an outbound change sets? Will it delete everything from the production that has deployed from the sandbox that is being shut down?
2. Can't we copy the outbound change sets of the sandbox that is being shut down in a different sandbox ?

Hope my questions make sense. Hoping to get a feedback from fellow community members.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as changeset has been deployed -- changes are merged into the environment, so it does not really matter what does happen to the source environment of changeset.

Comment: So @kurunve  if I'm understanding it correctly. That means its safe to delete a sandbox once the change sets are deployed to production. There will be no harm or side effect to the production environment. Is that right?

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapati yes that is correct.

Comment: @Himanshu
Is there a way we can copy the outbound change sets to another sandbox. Our plan is to merge the multiple unused sandboxes into one sandbox and shutdown the other unused sandboxes.

Comment: you can't copy the changeset but you can upload changeset to your another sandbox and deploy the changes.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What does it mean deleting an outbound change sets? Will it delete everything from the production that has deployed from the sandbox that is being shut down?

**No**. Deleting an outbound change set does not mean it will delete everything from production that has been deployed. In a scenario if a sandbox is deleted, then any outbound change set from that sandbox which has not been yet deployed in any target org gets deleted. Refer to the below excerpt from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_inbound_view_unavailable.htm&type=5):

> When the source sandbox is deleted or refreshed, assume that the change set is no longer available for deployment in the target org.

Remember, anything deployed in Production is always the golden copy and any change in sandboxes or even deleting or refreshing (which anyways is a copy of Production) a sandbox does not impact Production org.

> 2. Can't we copy the outbound change sets of the sandbox that is being shut down in a different sandbox ?

**No**. Because the time you delete a sandbox, any pending deployment outbound change sets are not available in the target org (again refer to the same excerpt as above).

Your options here are:

1. Recommended - Extract your contents in a source control and then make that available for any future deployment.
2. Deploy the change set to another sandbox and then only proceed deleting the source sandbox